# Help with numerical simulation of a backwards ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, delay-differential-equations

This is a toy problem of a much more complicated ODE system. Suppose I have the following ODE
$$\frac{dx}{ds} = kx-c, \quad x(0) = 1$$
Assume that $s<t$ and that $x(s)$ is the value of some multivariate function say $x(s) = \Psi(1,0,t-s,t)$. Now the text says solving the equation for each value of $t$ gives us $S(t) = x(t)$. How can we calculate $S(t)$ numerically? Do I have to use a delayed ODE solver?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please check again your source for clearer notation, or write more about your motivation for this question? It is something about the flow, but $\Psi$ has too many arguments for that. // Numerical integration backwards is the same as forwards, only that the time steps are negative. The formulas for the steps remain unchanged.